# Thoughts on this/that

Tags: meaning, word-choice, this-that

I'm talking with someone and I want to know what they think about a specific topic (which was discussed priviously), which of the following should I use:

- What are your thoughts on that

or

- What are your thoughts on this

Comment: I have thoughts on this 'n that.  Which do you want?

Comment: @HotLicks, if I said "I just bought a house, what are your thoughts on X", which one should i use?

Comment: @Trey Either would be alright. They tend to be interchangeable. Normally I would say "that", unless I were at the time gesturing toward something e.g. a notice, or some documents, then "this" would seem more apt.

Comment: Use "this" if you're conceptually (or literally) holding the object of the discussion.  Use "that" if the object is some distance away.

Comment: @HotLicks Of course the object could be something abstract, which you couldn't hold in your hand - such as Plato's philosophy of forms. Now generally I would say "that", but if I were holding an account of it written in a book, and I had just read it for the first time I might say "What do you think of this". I've noticed that when you send someone something by email, they will often reply "Thank you for this" - but my own inclination is to "thank you for that". I'm not sure why.

Comment: @WS2 - Even if it's abstract there is a distinction between "here" -- what I was just talking about -- and "over there" -- a topic raised by someone else.